# Keep get parameter in all url

Tags: url, parameters, assign

I'm using prestashop and i want to run a/b test. It means you test 2 different templates of your website in the same time as the traffic is redirected 50% to templateA and 50% to templateB.

I have to theme in my folder :

-ThemeA
-ThemeB

To run the test i need to access themeB via a different url form themeA.

So in the folder "/config" i modified the file setting.inc.php like this :

`if(isset($_GET['ab']))
    {
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeB');
    }
    else{
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeA');
    }`

Now i can reach themeb by typing : www.myshop.com/?ab

My problem is, whenever i click a link, the ?ab parameter is lost and it goes back to template A.

I found someone using another cms that resolved to problem using this code :

```
`$this->redirect(array('name')); `
```

But i don't know how to adapt it to prestashop and where should i put it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One quick workaround might be using session, if session is started ([http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php][1])  before your "theme check".

```
// Page => watermelons.php    
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['ab']) || isset($_SESSION['ab'])) {
    $_SESSION['ab'] = 'themeB';
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeB');
} else{
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeA');
}

echo _THEME_NAME_;

?>
<br /><a href="coconuts.php">go to coconuts</a>



// Page => coconuts.php    
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['ab']) || isset($_SESSION['ab'])) {
    $_SESSION['ab'] = 'themeB';
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeB');
} else{
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeA');
}

echo _THEME_NAME_;

?>
<br /><a href="watermelons.php">go to watermelons</a>
```

Comment: Ok actually it's weird, it dosen't change anything : i go to themeB by typing : www.myshop.com?ab. When i click a link, the parameter is lost and it goes back to themeA without the parameter

Comment: i used :                                                 session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['ab']) || isset($_SESSION['ab'])) { 
    $_SESSION['ab'] = 'themeB';
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeB'); 
    } else{ 
    define('_THEME_NAME_', 'themeA'); 
    } But it didnt work either

Comment: Thanks for helping again. The thing is prestashop is using .tpl file where i cannot put php in it. Im tried to use session_start(); at the very top of my .tpl files but i got no chance either. The way prestashop cms is built makes it very hard for me to use session like explained in the link you send me...